# Techniques for Practice with Looper pedal?

Tags: practice, looping

I decided to treat myself to a TC Electronic Ditto looper this holiday season, which will arrive soon.

I got out of my regular gig about a year ago, and I haven't been practicing much. What are some practice techniques you can do with a loop pedal and what aspects of musicianship are they good for?

Comment: I just saw this video a couple of days ago [by a pianist who began experimenting with a Ditto looper pedal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COo0uVv9YfU); you might find something of interest there.

Comment: That's exactly the video that made me buy it

Answer (score 1):

As a guitar student, one way I use my looper pedal to practice improvisation is on chord changes in a progression. This can lead to many different forms of practice, such as scale exercises in a certain key, which can lead to exercising improvisation in that progression and keeping up with chord changes, or if you want to get really jazz-y you can also practice mode changes with non-diatonic chord progressions. Loop pedals are immensely useful for improving my musicianship and I would suggest purchasing one to any student (or at least any student of an instrument that can plug in to a loop pedal).

Answer (score 0):

Getting the timing right can sometimes be a bit of a challenge, but it comes with practice. Some video's to get you started with beginner tips:

Carl Wockner :

KT Tunstall :